# How to show that repeated histogram equalizations always give the same result?

Tags: image-processing, histogram

I need some direction in solving this problem of mine. The question is in the title essentially. After you use histogram equalization on an image, if you use it again on the equalized image show that the result will be the same. I can easily demonstrate this using any kind of examples. However I'm not sure how to show it generally.

I know the formula is:

[(L - 1) / MN] * $\sum_{j=0}^{\k} n_j

where L represents image bits (in a 4-bit image this would be 16), M and N represent the dimensions of the image, and n_j represents the amount of pixels that occur for that intensity value. I also know that if you ignore MN but still multiply by L - 1 you can round the result to obtain the new mappings of intensity values (because then n_j is replaced by pr(n_j) which represents the probability of pixels having the pixel intensity represented by j).

I think I have the tools to solve this problem. But I don't know where to start since the result may get really ugly. Can someone help point me in the correct direction, please?